# Nested Fragments. How to know when all of them are attached to the activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

My application uses multiple nested fragments. Some of these fragments are placeholders. When I try to replace placeholders with initial set of fragments I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

I am sure that activity is fine and the issue is caused by fragments not being attached to the activity. So how do know when all nested fragments are attached to the activity?

**Additional information about my setup:**

I have an `Activity` that has fragment declaration in it's layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/rightPane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.company.PagerFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `PagerFragment` is the host for view pager.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I put two `Fragment`s into the pager. They serve as placeholders.

I want to replace placeholders with initial fragments but when I initiate the replacement in activity's `onCreate` method I get the aforementioned exception.

Everything works fine if I use `new Handler().postDelayed(..)` in activity's `onCreate` method. I would rather to not use the delay approach for obvious reasons.

I tried to replace placeholders in other activity's methods like `onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onResumeFragments()`, `onPostResume()` but that didn't help.

EDIT:

```
public class PagerFragment extends Fragment
{
    ..
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_right_pane, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            m_primary = new PlaceholderFragment();
            m_secondary = new PlaceholderFragment();
        }
        else
        {
            FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
            m_primary = (PlaceholderFragment)fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState, FRAGMENT_TAG_PRIMARY);
            m_secondary = (PlaceholderFragment)fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState, FRAGMENT_TAG_SECONDARY);
        }

        Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[] { m_primary, m_secondary };
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);
        m_viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        m_viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        m_viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        m_viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    }
..
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the PagerFragment?